# Как заполнять дивами сначала сверху-вниз, потом слева-направо?

Tags: css3, вёрстка, css, html5

То есть как значки на рабочем столе виндовс - доходит до низа, если выходит за нижнюю границу контейнера то выводится на следующем столбце сверху в зависимости от высоты контейнера (другой див, выполняющего роль "рабочего стола"). При смене размера окна браузера все перестраивается. Например если задать стиль

```
float:left
```

, то будет: слева-направо, потом сверху-вниз, а мне наоборот - сверху-вниз, потом слева-направо. Без js и на любом браузере. Другими словами мне нужен аналог:

```
float:top;
```

, если бы такой был в css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS3 columns Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp)

Comment: Делал, не универсально

Comment: У вас в тэгах к вопросу CSS3 и HTML5. Уже не универсально. Аналогов в css2 и html4 нету, javascript остается только...

Comment: Для старых версий браузеров хай не показывает, лишь бы во всех новых версиях, вот под этим подразумевал универсально, а там совместимость со всякими нетскейп навигаторами с рулем или пятыми ие не нужен. Думал может хитрый прием кто знает с вложенными дивами или как-то так

Comment: ... или при построении на сервере, абсолют + отступы)

Comment: Да, думал на пхп выстроить, но тогда при изменении окна не будут перестраиваться - не чистая работа

Comment: [Multi Column List with jQuery][1]

[1]:http://codeasily.com/jquery/multi-column-list-with-jquery